# In Lumen Laravel 5.4 POST method not working

Tags: lumen

I'm using lumen laravel as backend. I'm trying to do a POST method from frontend using angular2. GET method is working fine. But when trying with POST method I'm getting the error as 405 Method Not Allowed [Method not allowed 405 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzz58.png)

routes/web.php
    $app->post('/insert_data', 'ExampleController@testInsert');

Comment: post your angular code that is trying to invoke the POST method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the data that we need to send. You have to stringify your JSON data before sending it. For Eg: JSON.stringify(values)

```
this._http.post('http://local.amazonlaravel.com/api/add_products',JSON.stringify(values),{
})
.subscribe(
  res => {        
    // console.log(values);
  },
  err => {
    console.log("Error occured");
  }
);
```